# Link_to_if - text still present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I want to do a conditional `link_to` which is displayed only if the user is logged in as an admin. So I did this :

**Application Controller**

```
def confirm_admin
 if session[:role] == "admin"
   @isAdmin = true
 else
   flash[:notice] = "Vous n'avez pas les droits pour accéder à cette page."
   redirect_to root_path
   return false
 end
end
```

**View**

```
<%= link_to_if is_admin, 'Editer l\'idée', edit_idee_path(@idee), :class => "editer custom-button" %>
```

The link disappeared but the text is still present, do you have any idea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link_to_if` only makes the text no-link text; it removes the link from the text, not the text itself.

What you are trying to do, you can achieve it through following code:

```
<% if is_admin %>
  <%= link_to 'Editer l\'idée', edit_idee_path(@idee), :class => "editer custom-button" %>
<% end %>
<%# Now, it will remove both: link as well as text. %>
```

Comment: Yes, I knew that I could do this with <% if is_admin %>, but I thought that the entire text would disappear,  thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is to add an empty block at the end of the link_to_if statement, this will display the text when conditional is true and not display it when the conditional is false.

E.g.

```
flash[:notice]= "Some text that will always show. 
#{view_context.link_to_if(user.exists?,
'A hyperlink that will show based on conditional', 
user_path)**{}**}"
```